# UIPickerView crashes when I open it?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uipickerview

I have a UIPickerView, and it just crashes whenever I try to open it. I want the user to be able to select the tail number from the plane they made. **This is my code:**

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfComponentsInPickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView {
        return 1;
}

- (NSInteger)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView numberOfRowsInComponent:(NSInteger)component {
    NSLog(@"%i", (int)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"planeNum"]);
    return (NSInteger)[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"planeNum"];
}

NSMutableArray *tailPickerOptions;

- (NSString *)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)thePickerView titleForRow:(NSInteger)row forComponent:(NSInteger)component {

    NSInteger num = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]integerForKey:@"planeNum"];

    while (num > 0) {
        --num;
        tailPickerOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
        NSString *dTailNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plane%liTailNumber", (long)num]]];
        [tailPickerOptions addObject:dTailNumber];
        NSLog(@"%@", dTailNumber);
    }

    return tailPickerOptions[row];

}
```

Comment: What does the debugger say?

Comment: 2014-07-05 10:41:50.423 FlightLog Pro[563:60b] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayM objectAtIndex:]: index 1 beyond bounds [0 .. 0]'
*** First throw call stack:
libc++abi.dylib: terminating with uncaught exception of type

Comment: Your `tailPickerOptions` array is empty.

Comment: How? I added stuff to it.

Comment: Are you sure you did? `NSLog` the array and check before `return tailPickerOptions[row]`.

Comment: It prints NULL. Hmm. I added stuff to it with addObject.

Comment: You did not. Maybe num is 0, so you never add anything to your array.

Comment: Num is NOT zero. I know it isn't. Num is the amount of planes the person has added, which I know is not 0; I have logged it out.

Comment: Why is your `tailPickerOptions` variable declared outside of any method? And why do you rebuild your data over and over every time a picker view title is requested? That is so inefficient. Build all of your data once.

Answer (score 1):

The line of code:
`tailPickerOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];`
causes `tailPickerOptions` to be initialized multiple times (once each time through the `while` loop) and thus will only ever have one object (at index 0, or, as the exception says, "bounds[0..0]"). Move it outside the `while` loop. E.g.,

```
tailPickerOptions = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];
while (num > 0) {
        --num;

        NSString *dTailNumber = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@", [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"Plane%liTailNumber", (long)num]]];
        [tailPickerOptions addObject:dTailNumber];
        NSLog(@"%@", dTailNumber);
    }
```